# Why does alarm() cause fgets() to stop waiting?

Tags: c, fgets, alarm, sigaction

I am playing around with signals in C.  My main function basically asks for some input using `fgets(name, 30, stdin)`, and then sits there and waits.  I set an alarm with `alarm(3)`, and I reassigned SIGALRM to call a function `myalarm` that simply calls `system("say PAY ATTENTION")`.  But after the alarm goes off, `fgets()` stops waiting for input and my main fn continues on.  This happens even if I change `myalarm` to just set some variable and do nothing with it.

```
void myalarm(int sig) {
    //system("say PAY ATTENTION");
    int x = 0;
}

int catch_signal(int sig, void (*handler)(int)) { // when a signal comes in, "catch" it and "handle it" in the way you want
    struct sigaction action;  // create a new sigaction
    action.sa_handler = handler;  // set it's sa_handler attribute to the function specified in the header
    sigemptyset(&action.sa_mask);  // "turn all the signals in the sa_mask off?" "set the sa_mask to contian no signals, i.e. nothing is masked?"
    action.sa_flags = 0; // not sure, looks like we aren't using any of the available flags, whatever they may be

    return sigaction(sig, &action, NULL);  // here is where you actually reassign- now when sig is received, it'll do what action tells it
}

int main() {

    if(catch_signal(SIGINT, diediedie)== -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't map the SIGINT handler");
        exit(2);
    }

    if(catch_signal(SIGALRM, myalarm) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't map the SIGALAM handler\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    alarm(3);

    char name[30];
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    fgets(name, 30, stdin);

    printf("Hello, %s\n", name);

    return 0;

}
```

Why does `alarm()` make `fgets()` stop waiting for input?

Edit: Added code for my `catch_signal` function, and, as per one of the comments, used `sigaction` instead of `signal`, but the issue persisted.

Comment: See `man 7 signal`, subheading "Interruption of system calls and library functions by signal handlers"

Comment: I'm seeing this: "If a blocked call to one of the following interfaces is interrupted by a signal handler, then the call will be automatically restarted after the signal handler returns if the SA_RESTART flag was used; otherwise the call will fail with the error EINTR..." and fgets() isn't listed as one of the functions that can be restarted.  Is what I'm trying to do not possible?

Comment: `fgets()` is using the `read` syscall under the hood. BTW, on my system it is not interrupted (Arch Linux x86_64)

Comment: @Retr0spectrum: Your C implementation may detect EINTR  and restart the read for you.

Comment: You could wrap fgets() in a loop to retry it if errno equals EINTR.. i.e. something like:  do{ fgets(name, 30, stdin); }while ( errno == EINTR);

Comment: You've not shown `catch_signal()` but I guess you use `signal()` and not `sigaction()` and that means that the `read()` called by `fgets()` is not restarted.  Use `sigaction()` to gain control over this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is most likely going to be OS/system specific.

(As stated by Retr0spectrum) The fgets() function often makes system calls, such as read().  System calls can terminate if a signal is detected.  In the case of this question, the fgets() function has made a system call (likely the read() system call) to read a character from stdin.  The SIGALRM causes the system call to terminate, and set errno to EINTR.  This also causes the fgets() function to terminate, without reading any characters.

This is not unusual.  It's just how the OS implements signals.

To avoid this problem, I will often wrap fgets() function in a loop like this:

```
do {
   errno=0;
   fgets(name, 30, stdin);
   } while(EINTR == errno);
```

It will require that you: `#include <stdio.h>`

(As suggested by TonyB).

Comment: I'd add a [citation needed] after *“fgets() function often makes system calls”*  ;-)

Comment: The loop here is wrong. Stdio functions are not restartable like that; buffer contents & file position are unspecified after error.  If you're using stdio and don't want a signal to be a fatal error you **must** use `sigaction` with `SA_RESTART`.

Answer (score 3):

As to the question of *why* the alarm signal interrupts the read, there are two reasons:

1. It's the way Unix used to do it, and it was because it was much easier to implement in the OS.  (On the one hand this sounds kind of lame, but the "don't sweat the hard stuff" attitude was responsible in part for the success of Unix in the first place.  This is the topic of Richard P. Gabriel's epic *Worse Is Better* essay.)
2. It makes it easy to implement a read that times out and gives up, if that's what you want.  (See my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46019056/time-limit-for-a-scanf-in-c).)

But, as other comments and answers discuss, the interrupting behavior is somewhat obsolete; most modern systems (Unix and Linux, at least) now automatically restart an interrupted system call such as `read`, more or less as you were wishing.  (Also as pointed out elsewhere, if you know what you're doing you may be able to select between the two behaviors.)

In the end, though, it's a grey area; I'm pretty sure the C standard leaves it unspecified or implementation-defined or undefined what happens if you interrupt a system call with an alarm or other signal.